# How to suggest user's email list with AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want my `AutoCompleteTextView` to suggest a user a list of emails (registered on his own device) when he starts typing as shown in the screenshot below. Suppose that a user has 3 emails registered in hiw phone (`felix@gmail.com`, `felix@yahoo.com` and `felix@facebook.com`), then in the `AutoCompleteTextView` when he'll try to write `felix@` it suggests the whole list of 3 emails containing `felix@`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `android:inputType="textAutoComplete"`?

Comment: Try this https://en.proft.me/2018/04/5/how-get-registered-email-address-programmatically-/ .. and load list of emails in autoCompleteTextView